# .net 4.0 Routing with QueryStrings

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, url-rewriting, url-routing, webforms

I realize there are a ton of articles and resources out there on this subject, but all seem to only show how to move a querystring like **category=shoes** around the url to a differently place, like this **products/{category}**

Well i have the following querystring: **profile.aspx?q=98c2b15f-90c3-4a7f-a33f-0e34b106877e**

I was trying to implement a RoutHandler to query the DB to find the users name and create a url like **mydomain.com/usersname**

This is what i tried *(everything is hard coded right now till i get it working)*:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("Profiles", new System.Web.Routing.Route("profile/{profile}", new RouteHandler()));
}
```

And this is the handler class:

```
public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    string username = requestContext.RouteData.Values["profile"] as string;

    HttpContext.Current.Items["q"] = "98c2b15f-90c3-4a7f-a33f-0e34b106877e";
    return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/pub/profile.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
}
```

Profile.aspx actually looks for the "q" querystring. And with the above setup, it does not find it.

What am i doing wrong? How do i route or rewrite the url so that it is pretty + keep it so the page can find the querystrings it needs?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - If you are using .net framework 4 you dont need to create any handler, you can directly use MapPageRoute method to a route.

Answer to your question-
use can use foreach loop like below in handler rather than looking for "profile" specifically.

```
    foreach (var urlParm in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
         requestContext.HttpContext.Items[urlParm.Key] = urlParm.Value;

    return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler
```

and in your routed page you should check for

```
    string userName = this.Context.Items["profile"].ToString();       // "userName" and is set as route parameters in Global.asax
```

You set VirtualPath in RouteHandler constructor

```
 RouteHandler(string virPath)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virPath;
    }
```

see these links for more information- 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc668201.aspx